# PublishCucumberReport - Can't find output path of cucumber report

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cucumber, report

The plugin can't find files and generate HTML report on Azure DevOps

Azure Devops plugin - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaciejMaciejewski.azure-pipelines-cucumber

azure-pipelines.yml

```
jobs:
  # Build Electron
  - job: UserAcceptanceTest
    displayName: E2E-Tests
    pool:
      name: ado-win-pool
    timeoutInMinutes: 120
    steps:
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          sourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
          targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: 'Publishing build artifacts'
        inputs:
          targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

      - task: NodeTool@0
        displayName: 'Install Node 12.x'
        inputs:
          versionSpec: 12.x

      - task: PublishCucumberReport@1
        displayName: 'Publish Cucumber Report'
        inputs:
          jsonDir: target/results/cucumber/
          outputPath: target/results/cucumber/
```

Actual:

```
  Found 0 matching C:/agent/_work/13/s/target/results/cucumber pattern
    ##[warning]Error: Not found outputPath: C:\agent\_work\13\s\target\results\cucumber
    Finishing: Publish Cucumber Report
```

Expected:
Found cucumber JSON file.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me if it helped you to fix this issue

Comment: Particularly yes, full response gave under your answer. Thanks for efforts.

Comment: That's great it was fixed.  You can [accept above answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) since it worked out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the problem is in the path provided for the cucumber report.
It should be a path to the folder with cucumber reports in json format, but not to some particular json.

So, the correct snippet in yaml would be:

```
        - task: PublishCucumberReport@1
        displayName: 'Publish Cucumber Report'
        inputs:
        jsonDir: target/results/cucumber/
        outputPath: target/results/cucumber/
```

Comment: Yes, it was the root cause. Path change solved a problem.
Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

In above yaml pipeline, you didnot have the step to run your cucumber test to generate the cucumber JSON file.

If the cucumber JSON file is already existing in your repo. Then the error from PublishCucumberReport task is because the directory `target/results/cucumber` doesnot exist in your repo.

Then You need to check where the cucumber JSON file is located in your repo and specify the correct path for PublishCucumberReport task.

If there is no cucumber JSON fileexisting in your repo. You should add steps in the yaml pipeline to run your tests.

If you have your test scripts configured in the package.json file, like below(`report` folder must exist in the repo):

[image]

You can just run the `npm test` to execute your tests and generate the json report in the `report` folder. See below;

```
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Install Node 12.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 12.x

- script: |
   npm install
   npm test
  displayName: 'Run tests'
 

- task: PublishCucumberReport@1
  inputs:
    jsonDir: report
    outputPath: report
```

If there is no test script defined in your  package.json file. You can run the cucumber-js command in the yaml pipeline to generate the json file. See below:

```
- script: |
   #npm install cucumber
   npm install 
   ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js features -f json:report/cucumber_report.json
  displayName: 'Run tests'
```

Comment: We are using java instead of Node, the problem was in the path.
The path should be to the folder but not to the file and also plugin can exist without the node js plugin.